# What is a common good connector for wire that carries ~20A that doesn't generate heat?

Tags: current, connector

I am building a DYI solar power plant with custom built wi-fi connected power meter with two 20 A, ACS712 current sensors.

I put everything in a plastic box with banana connectors, on picture here:

[image: Metering box]

I thought these banana plugs are going to be enough because they look like a big piece of metal, but after over a month of smooth operation, during very sunny day one of connectors melted:

[image: Melted]

Current that was going through was about 15 A at the time, it seems that while banana plug is quite big, its metal plates have very small points where they touch the opposing connector and as such they get hot very easily with higher currents. I noticed all eight connectors were eventually getting warm.

What type of connector is best suited for this kind of application, so that it is reasonably cheap, common, doesn't exceed 60°C when under 20 A and of similar size? (Not too bulky like MC4, ideally possible to screw to plastic box like this.)

Comment: Any connector will always generate heat when carrying current. How much heat is tolerable?

Comment: @Hearth less than heat that would hurt you or melt the plastic box I guess.

Comment: And how much is that? That's also a difficult question because it's not *heat* that does either of those things, it's *temperature*. And temperature is *very* complicated to calculate. I would suggest just looking for connectors that are rated for 15 A; that's a pretty large amount of current, but not large enough that it's hard to find suitable connectors. I've even seen banana plugs rated for it (actually rated for quite a lot more, and quite expensive; not what you want here), though they're quite different from your normal banana plugs.

Comment: Personally, I would probably use Anderson powerpole connectors here, but I don't know your use case and what other requirements you might have. Shop around. Good distributors like Mouser or Digikey have parametric search, so you can search by rated current.

Comment: If you're looking for something cheap and easy to find, consider using connectors designed for car batteries and similar.

Comment: Temperature: Ideally less than 60 celsius. The use-case is pretty simple, one wire goes from solar panels through this box to solar regulator (box is measuring current and voltage, both + and - goes through it). And then there is another wire from lead-acid battery that goes through this box again to load. This box has 2 independent current and voltage meters (that's why 8 banana plugs) that calculate watts, store the measured data and expose them via wi-fi / API for further processing.

Comment: In addition to the excellent suggestions already posted, you might consider increasing the size of the wire.  The contact point inside the connector is the electrical weak link and the wiring going to and from the junction is generally relied upon to wick away much of the heat especially since in many connectors the contact area is in the middle of a chunk of plastic.

Comment: Banana jacks were the defacto standard for high power audio systems for years.   They can handle the current, but you need "good" ones as others have mentioned.    Have you considered using a metal box instead of plastic????

Comment: Look for '4mm gold bullet' connectors, which are commonly used for electric RC racing cars eg. https://www.amainhobbies.com/4mm-bullet-connectors-wire-electronics-cars-trucks/c3202

Answer (score 3):

There are high current 4mm banana plugs, and lightweight, cheap, ones.

Unfortunately, you get what you pay for, and the better ones will cost more. They will probably only be obtainable from reputable electronic suppliers, not the auction-type sites. You should look for a 'bunched pin' type, which has multiple spring rods. Types with a single spring rod, or a loose spring cage, are not going to give you a much higher contact resistance.

A good solid turned socket will also help dissipate heat better than one formed from thin stock.

That only gets you to the better end of a banana plug connection. It would be better to use connectors rated for the current.

Comment: I have banana plugs at my workplace that are rated for 500 A (pulsed only); they're on (relatively) enormous 6-gauge wire and have an unusual construction--by screwing down a collar on them, the banana plug itself expands outward, pressing tightly into the sides of the jack. I have no idea where you would buy them; they came with an extraordinarily expensive piece of test equipment.

Comment: I worked in the stock room at General Radio, briefly in my college years.  They made their own banana plugs, and other sundry connectors where they made a difference to precision measurements.

Answer (score 3):

"What type of connector" may be the wrong question.  The *broad category* of connectors you're looking for is connectors designed to carry current or handle power.

The only reliable way to buy a connector and be reasonably certain that it'll stand a given current is to find one from a reputable source (i.e. *not* an auction site, or a hobby site, or a company that specializes in selling floor-sweepings from countries known for low quality products).  Then *read the datasheet*.  You want to find that your connector is specified for *your* current or more, at *your* operating temperature.  If the data sheet doesn't specify a *current* **and** an *operating temperature*, then that's a strong indication that whoever is selling it to you didn't pay attention to making it work under those circumstances.

This is one of those areas where attempting to save money by buying stuff off of the hobby or auction market will leave you endlessly messing around with marginal stuff.  If you *already know what you're doing* there's some surplus vendors that have decent stuff -- but that's a huge roll of the dice, and again, you need to know exactly what you want and who you're dealing with.  Assuming that you live in a country with a robust electronics industry, just find a reliable distributor* that'll sell stuff in quantity 1, and accept that the price will be higher than flea-market prices.

* I.e., DigiKey, Mouser or Newark in the USA, Farnell in the UK.  Unfortunately my knowledge of who sells what doesn't go beyond that.

Comment: RS Components is also a big one in the UK, and Arrow in the US (might be worldwide?). Mouser operates worldwide as well, though they're based in the US.

Answer (score 1):

For your application, I recommend [plastic power circular connectors](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?sm=N&nm=N&bm=K&c=round_conn&u=circular_conn&o=plastic_power_circular_conn) (my site), a broad class of relatively inexpensive connectors for exterior use (accessible to the end user) and high current. For example, the [Weipu SP or SY series](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?sm=N&nm=N&bm=K&c=round_conn&u=circular_conn&o=plastic_power_circular_conn&fl=%C2%8000000000000000000000000000-140-%7C2%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C) which are readily available from eBay and Amazon.

[image]

{Courtesy Weipu}

Comment: I was actually considering those, but I am not sure how could I mount them to that plastic box, they look more like connectors for connecting two wires together. The box is indoors so it doesn't need to have IP rating.